# Is there a nice closed form for inversion on the boundary of an orthogonal circle?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

I have two circles $A$ and $B$, such that $A \perp B$.

Let's say I have some point $a\in A$, I'm interested in where the inversion of $a$ over $B$, which I will call $a'$ is.  Now since $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal this point will be on $A$ as well.

Additionally we can very easily give classification for $4$ points.  The two intersections of $A$ and $B$ are fixed points, and the two points which are equidistant from these intersections are each others inverses.

For other points I can use a compass and straight edge to manually find their inversion quite easily.  But I would like to work algebraically.

I'm wondering if there is some nice closed form for this.  We can w.l.o.g. fix the size and location of $A$ as well as one of the intersection points between $A$ and $B$. The nrelationship between $A$ and $B$ can be represented as the angle between the two intersections, and $a$ can be represented as the angle from the fixed intersection point.

[image: Circle diagram]

So I'm looking for a function which takes these two angles and spits out a third angle representing the angle of $a'$ from $x_0$.

Comment: "The relationship between $A$ and $B$ can be w.l.o.g. represented as the angle between the two intersections and the center of $A$." I'm not following what you mean here. Could you elaborate? Possibly draw a picture?

Comment: @TheoBendit We might imagine first fixing the size and location of $A$, this can clearly be done wlog.  From there since $B$ must be orthogonal we know that given it's two intersection points with $A$ it can be uniquely determined.  We then can say fix one of the intersection points as the reference for the entire problem, and then $B$ is exactly determined by the second intersection point.  We can thus represent this as a single angle.  I will make a diagram shortly.

Comment: @TheoBendit A diagram has been added.  Let me know if there is still any issue.

Comment: I guess I'm still not really sure what you're looking for. As Gianni pointed out, there is a general analytic formula for inversion in the sphere that works with or without the additional assumptions. I buy that this angle you've described determines the similarity class for this picture, but I don't see how this will help simplify the formula, as we still have to parameterise the circle $B$. Are you just looking for somebody to figure out the centre/radius of $B$, assuming $A$ is a unit circle, plug this into the inversion formula, and simplify?

Comment: @TheoBendit The general analytic formula is a bit sledgehammer.  You can go through the work of simplifying it, but it's really complicated and doesn't simplify simplify trivially.  Meanwhile this has a bunch of really nice properties that should make it easily tractable for other cleaner methods, for example there is a very nice linear homotopy between the circle and its inversion in hyperbolic space.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, if the center of inversion is $O$, the inverse $P'$ of a point $P$ is in the ray $\overrightarrow{OP}$. In your particular case, $a'$ is just the second intersection of that ray with $A$, hence if you have the coordinates of the center of $B$, the equation of $A$ and the coordinates of $a$, you can easily find $A'$.
There's also a [formula](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inversion.html) for inversion in analytic geometry. Finally, there's also an inversion [formula](https://mphitchman.com/geometry/section3-2.html#:%7E:text=Inversion%20in%20a%20circle%20centered,complex%20numbers%20except%20z0.&text=We%20usually%20denote%20inversion%20in,(%20z%20)%20%3D%20z%20%E2%88%97%20.) using complex numbers.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This answer seems to be a mixture of very elementary facts and links, which contain a lot of information, none of it particularly relevant.  It doesn't really address the question at hand at all, and comes off as pretty lazy attempt.

Comment: Well, when I wrote this answer, the question was way more incomplete that what it is now. I wasn't really sure of what you were asking at the moment, so I tried to cover every possible option I could think of, trying my best to help you. Considering what a badly written question it was, I think my answer wasn't lazy at all.

Comment: You are always able to ask for clarification if you need it.  But since this was asked, the only edit has been to add a diagram what was present in the text, no major changes have been made.